# How to replace the contents of two TXT file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, file

I have 2 (*.txt) file and I want to replace file1 text with file2 and file2 text with file1.

Here is my code:

```
f1 = open("20-file-1.txt", "r+")
f2 = open("20-file-2.txt", "r+")

f1_all_lines_list = f1.readlines()
f2_all_lines_list = f2.readlines()


f1.truncate(0)
f2.truncate(0)

f1.write(''.join(f2_all_lines_list))
f2.write(''.join(f1_all_lines_list))


f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Every thing works well but each time I run the code some space would be added before the first line string and after several run both txt files size increases and my IDE Stucks.

Here are txt files before running the code :
[image: Before running the code]

Here are txt files after first run:
[image: After running the code]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you please clarify why you do not just *rename* file-1 to file-2 and vice versa?

Comment: because actually this is an exercise from my teacher. :)

Comment: The problem is that ``truncate`` does *not* reset the position in the file. You can test this for example with ``f1.tell()`` after truncating. When writing after truncating, Python fills the missing/truncated characters with null bytes (``\x00``), then appends the content after the original end of file. Your viewer displays the null bytes as spaces, but they are not – you can check this when opening the file in ``"rb"`` binary mode in Python.

Comment: How to do this properly depends on the restrictions you have from your teacher. The closest solution to your current code is to ``f1.seek(0)`` and ``f2.seek(0)`` after truncating. The idiomatic solution is to open each file for reading once (``with open("20-file-1.txt") as f1: f1_content = f1.read()``), then open each file for writing once (``with open("20-file-2.txt") as f2: f2.write(f1_content)``).

Comment: Note that while homework questions are not off-topic per se, we still ask to pose them as proper questions (you've done that, by the way – kudos) *but* you should make clear which restrictions there are (*nudge* *nudge*). Homework is meant for teaching, and you will need answers from which you can learn, not those which only "solve" your problem – both in your interest and ours. Please take a look at the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) if you find the time.

Comment: Rename `file 2` to `tmp`, rename `file 1` to `file 2`, rename `tmp` to `file 1`. Instant, even for huge files, no memory footprint.